# Monit http status locally

Tags: monit

I'm using the following monit code to alert if the specified page isn't answering with http 200 status code:

```
check host gateway with address 127.0.0.1
    if failed
        port 7778
        protocol http
        request "/mypage/"
        status = 200
    then alert
```

Anyway, on monit 5.20 (default on my debian 9) I'm getting: FAILED to [127.0.0.1]:7778/mypage/ type TCP/IP protocol HTTP, why?

Editing: it seems related to the status getting back, which is 301, but still haven't figured out the reason.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I couldn't find the reason, but upgrading to latest monit version (5.26) the issue disappeared.